# Implementing class enablement

Tags: java, design-patterns

Considering a use case where a class needs to maintain it's enablement: what would be the advantage of segregating the behavior in two explicit methods (enable/disable) rather than having a single setter and when should I do it?

1:

```
private boolean enabled;

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

2:

```
private boolean enabled;

public void enable() {
    enabled = true;
}

public void disable() {
    enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: The second option looks like a valid approach, IMHO.

Comment: The first version is better imo, but naming it `setEnabled(boolean enabled)` would make more sense

Comment: 1.First method is like switching state of variable where as 2. method is precisely enable or disabling state of Boolean

Comment: I think above scenario following State Pattern is best way
 class Model
{
 private State currentState=State.OFF;
 
 enum State {
   OFF,ON
 }
 
 public String getCurrentState()
 {
  return currentState.toString();
 }
 
 public void changeState()
 {
  if(currentState==State.OFF)
  {
   currentState=State.ON;
  }
  else
  {
   currentState=State.OFF; 
  } 
 }
}

Comment: @kocko I reworded the question and I believe that that's a valuable answer to it, which haven't been given yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is a better and more natural way:

```
private boolean enabled = false;

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

Comment: I'd call the variable `enabled` and the setter `setEnabled`. This makes more sense than `isEnabled` as variable name.

Comment: I agree with @OlivierGrégoire 's opinion

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire you're right. I've edited.

Answer (score -1):

I'd argue the second as the method names are more explicitly describing the action, whereas the first is a bit ambiguous.

A usual Java pattern for this kind of flag (although I think this style/convention may be going out of vogue - would be interesting if someone more knowledgeable could give some insight on this) is to use `isEnabled` and `setEnabled()`, which is more explicit than the first but reduces redundancy in the code:

```
private boolean isEnabled;

private void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}
```

I'd also recommend making the methods `synchronized` as they will then be thread-safe; the body will be executed atomically ensuring there aren't any nasty race conditions on accessing the flag.

```
private boolean flag;

public synchronized void enable() {
    flag = true;
}

public synchronized void disable() {
    flag = false;
}
```

Another option to provide atomicity, which could be more useful for more complex methods that require access to the variable, is to use an `AtomicBoolean` which enforces atomicity in its accessor methods' implementation:

```
private AtomicBoolean flag;

public void enable() {
    flag.set(true);
}

public void disable() {
    flag.set(false);
}
```

Atomic variables are discussed in this Java tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html

Comment: If you use a `AtomicBoolean`, you have to use the `set` and `get` methods of the object. You can't assign a boolean value to an AtomicBoolean object reference (AutoBoxing is only for the Boolean wrapper class).

Comment: Ah, I assumed the auto-boxing would apply to subclasses of `Boolean` too. Thanks, @DavidSN, I'll change that now.

Comment: `AtomicBoolean` is not a subclass of `Boolean`. All the wrapper classes for the primitive types are final so they can't be subclassed.

Comment: My bad, I should have read the API... Thanks for letting me know, @DavidSN.

Answer (score -2):

You are actually doing the same thing.In my opinion he second option is better because you can enable/disable the method you want.You check the variable flag and you can see if your existing method is already enabled or not.

Comment: *"you can enable/disable the method you want"* How do you enable/disable a method? Also you can check the variable in the first approach too.